# C function is not returning the value

Tags: c, function

whats wrong with my code? im trying to return a value from function ignition_status, its not returning. I cant see any problem in my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
const char * ignition_status();
const char *ign_st;
int main()
{
printf("%s", ignition_status(1));
return 0;
}
const char * ignition_status(int st)
{
    if(st==1)
        {
           const char *ign_st="ON";
         }
    else
        {
           const char *ign_st="OFF";
         }
   return ign_st;
}
```

Thanks...

Comment: Shouldn't your `#include`s have a filename?

Comment: `const char *ign_st` inside the `if/else` blocks. That declares a *new* variable. Which only exists within the `if/else` blocks. What you are returning is then the global `ign_st` which has never been set. Remove those `const char *` or declare it as a local variable outside the `if/else` block. If you do the latter then best to use a different variable name so as not to confuse it with the global definition.

Comment: I'm quite sure your code isn't compiling, not only not returning what you expect. Is this correct?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the reply. im getting an warning that "unused variable ign_st", i think i've declared globally.

Comment: @user6161 What have you changed? If you have declared a local variable then, yes, the global variable is now unused. It's a warning not an error. So either add code to use the global variable or remove the global variable. Can't tell you which is right as don't know what further you want to do with your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments are pointing you to the right direction, here is a working sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char * ignition_status(int st)
{
    const char *ign_st;

    if(st==1) {
       ign_st="ON";
    } else {
       ign_st="OFF";
    }

    return ign_st;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%s", ignition_status(1));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `const char *` in front of `ign_st` in `if/else` statement:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
const char * ignition_status();
const char *ign_st;

int main() {
  printf("%s", ignition_status(1));
  return 0;
}

const char * ignition_status(int st) {
  if(st==1) {
    ign_st="ON";
  } else {
    ign_st="OFF";
  }

  return ign_st;
}
```